# Drake/Meshcat Visualizer example on ubuntu 22.04 with apt installation

Tags: drake

I am trying to use drake c++ on ubuntu 22.04 and I have installed it using nightly build. The installation is completed in opt folder and the example on drake-external-examples run fine.

Drake on ubuntu 22.04 is not supported by drake visualizer and I could not find the link of the visualizer in opt folder. I was struggling to find the equivalent format when installed using apt/tar format with cmake outside the drake source format. I have been able to run meshcat visualizer in drake source examples.

I will appreciate if there is a link to an example utilizing meshcat visualizer with apt/tar installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were previously using `/opt/drake/bin/drake-visualizer`, you'll probably be best suited to use [Meldis](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.visualization.meldis.html) as the next step.  Meldis will listen for LCM visualizer traffic just like `drake-visualizer` used to do.

Here's the command when using apt installed into `/opt/drake` on Ubuntu 22.04 as of Drake v1.12.0:

```
env PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages python3 -m pydrake.visualization.meldis -w
```

Sorry, I know that's a mouthful.  We'll work on adding a shortcut and better documentation in a future release.